# codeigniter get timestamp from database and format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I have a MYSQL table column of type `timestamp` and using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default when a new record is added.

The date field in my database table looks like this `2011-08-16 12:09:25` How is it possible to format that into `MM/DD/YY` to display on my site? I tried some functions from the [date helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html) but I get errors.

**note:** I'm trying to figure out how to use Codeigniter functions for this, if possible.

In the CI manual there are examples with `$timestamp = '1140153693';` but my database timestamp is a different format and get errors.

Comment: What errors do you get, and what does your code look like?

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @CyberJunkie: Please don't just say "I get errors".  Tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display a timestamp, just use the PHP Date class.  But since MySQL outputs timestamps as a string not an INT, you'll have to first convert the timestamp string to a timestamp INT using PHP's strtotime function.  The code looks like this:

```
echo date("m/d/y",strtotime($timestamp));
```

Date
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

StrToTime
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Thanks! I had just figured it out. I'm new to date and time in php.

Comment: Your approach actually seems simpler than the Codeigniter helper functions I use

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didn't properly explain the issue but solved it.

In order to use the **Codeigniter** date functions I had to convert the mysql ISO 8601 date format to a 32-bit integer.

I had to do the following

```
$unix = mysql_to_unix($row->message_date); //conversion to string

$datestring = "%m/%d/%Y";

echo mdate($datestring, $unix);
```

I was using the ISO 8601 format and getting errors.